# How to check if further `scroll down` is not possible using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Am using Selenium + python to scrap a page which has infinite scroll (basically scroll till max first 500 results are shown)

Using below code, am able to scroll to bottom of the page. Now i want to stop when further scrolling doesn't fetches any content. (say, page only has 200 results, i don't want to keep on scrolling assuming max 500 result)

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

I tried accessing `window.pageYOffset` but it's coming as None always.

Comment: Simply scroll until the last element is equal to the one from the previous iteration. You could also compare the `scrollHeight` with the previous iteration.

Comment: @FlorentB. `driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")` always returning 0, would you explain why?

Comment: @hafiz031, you'll have to to check the property on a scrollable container. To find out which on it is, inspect the area just on the left of the scroll bar. If it's under `<html>` then use `document.documentElement.scrollHeight`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Selenium with Chrome, not Firefox, but the following worked for me:

1. capture page height before scrolling down;
2. scroll down using key down;
3. capture page height after scrolling down;
4. if page height was same before and after scrolling, stop scrolling

My code looks like this:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("www.yourTargetURL.com")

reached_page_end = False
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while not reached_page_end:
      driver.find_element_by_xpath('//body').send_keys(Keys.END)   
      time.sleep(2)
      new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
      if last_height == new_height:
            reached_page_end = True
      else:
            last_height = new_height

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Not working for every website. Try and tell me : https://fr.finance.yahoo.com/quote/GM/history?period1=1596844800&period2=1612742400&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true

Comment: @LuckyFr - what's the issue you're getting? Is it a problem with the scrolling? A problem with the stopping-when-you-reach-the-end-of-the-page? Or a problem with the pop-up which appears before you actually access the data you're looking for?

Comment: It was scrolling a bit then was blocking. but found something.

Comment: OK - I'm not clear if you're still having an issue or not... I've not been able to replicate the problem (the code above works for me for that website, as long as I click on the 'J'accepte' button on the pop-up before attempting to scroll through the data). If you're still having an issue, let me know...

Answer (score 0):

You can check document.body.scrollTop by  before and after each scroll attempt if there is no data to fetch then this value will stay the same

```
distanceToTop = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollTop);")
```

Comment: This answer sounds like an attempt to use the method given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717120/twitter-scroll-down-of-all-posts-using-selenium-python. Thought I would post the link in case anyone else is looking for something similar. (The idea is to get the page height, then scroll down, then get the page height again, then compare both page heights. If both are the same, then there is no further to scroll.)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, if someone is using `playwright`. This code snippet is very similar to the [ATJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65834349/15164646) answer.

```py
import time
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright


def run(playwright):
    page = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False).new_page()
    page.goto("URL")

    reached_end = False
    last_height = page.evaluate("() => document.body.scrollHeight")  # scrollHeight: 5879

    while not reached_end:
        page.keyboard.press("End")
        time.sleep(2)

        new_height = page.evaluate("() => document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            reached_end = True
        else:
            last_height = new_height

    page.close()


with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a hard count while scrolling and as soon we reach that max count we get out of the loop.

```
    b=0;
    boolean x = true;
    while (x){
        WebElement button = null;
        try {
          button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='vjs_video_3']/div[7]/div[1]/button[1]"));
          x= false;
        } catch (Exception ex){
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            js.executeScript("javascript:window.scrollBy(50, 80)");
            
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            js.executeScript("javascript:window.scrollBy(50, 50)");  
            b++;
            System.out.println("\n"+ b);
            if(b>50) {
                System.out.println("out!");
                break;
            }
```

//              js.executeScript("javascript:window.scrollBy(50, 180)");
//              Thread.sleep(1000);
//              js.executeScript("javascript:window.scrollBy(50, 150)");   // button is missing

```
        }
        

    }
}
```