# Twitter scroll down of all posts using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium with Python. I am trying to scroll down of a twitter page. But it doesn't scroll down till the end of the page. It stops in the middle and twitter shows a message: `"back to top"`. It doesn't even shows all the posts of last one month of a page. This is my page:

```
users = ['BBCWorld']

    username = browser.find_element_by_class_name("js-username-field")
    username.send_keys("username")
    password = browser.find_element_by_class_name("js-password-field")
    password.send_keys("password")

    signin_click = WebDriverWait(browser, 500000).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page-container"]/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/button'))
        )
    signin_click.click()

    for user in users:
        # User's profile
        browser.get('https://twitter.com/' + user)

        time.sleep(0.5)

        SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

        # Get scroll height
        last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

        while True:
            # Scroll down to bottom
            browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")

            # Wait to load page
            time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)


            # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
            new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")



        # Quit browser
        browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot this:

```
while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)


    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    # break condition
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Also you have `SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5` it is not very much, and when number of posts to load becomes bigger, twitter slows down. You have to increase this pause. I would try `SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 2`

***PS:*** it is not very effective to use hard coded pause. Instead you can try to locate spinner or whatever, when twitter loads new content and wait until spinner disappear. This would be more elegant.

Comment: new_height is getting equal to last_height just after 2-3 scrolls and it's breaking the while loop

Comment: Have you increased the pause?